# TestNG @Test and @AfterMethod are not executing and also not take the screenshot

Tags: java, selenium, testng

The `@BeforeMethod` executes however, it will not execute `@Test` and `@AfterMethod`

Not sure why it will not execute after the `@BeforeMethod` and also not take the ScreenShot

**Console**

```java
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.0
Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb) on port 33501
Only local connections are allowed.
Mar 06, 2020 4:05:25 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb) on port 43792
Only local connections are allowed.
Mar 06, 2020 4:05:31 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

Failed Test

Failed Test

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at utility.CapSc.captureScreenShot(CapSc.java:16)
    at autobillAutomation.listeners.CustomListener.onTestFailure(CustomListener.java:32)
    at org.testng.internal.TestListenerHelper.runTestListeners(TestListenerHelper.java:66)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runTestResultListener(TestInvoker.java:210)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:814)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:145)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Classes:

```java
public class Setup {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void initialize() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver_1.exe");

        // deleteCookies
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        // navigateToPage
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.gmail.com");
        // setWindowSize | 1920x1080
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
        // manageTimeouts
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // switchToTheTestWindow
        String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);
    }

}


@Listeners(CustomListener.class)
public class Login {

    public static WebDriver driver;


    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        Setup.initialize();
    }
    @Test
    public void login() throws InterruptedException {
        // Test name: Login
        // Step # | name | target | value | comment
        // 3 | click | id=email | |
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).click();
        // 4 | type | id=email | test@email.com |
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("test@email.com");
        // 5 | click | id=password | |
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
        // 6 | type | id=password | pwd |
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("pwd");
        // 7 | click | css=.login-button | |
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".login-button")).click();
        // Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().contains("Dashboard"));
        // 8 | click | css=.place-holder-image | |
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".place-holder-image")).click();
        // 9 | click | css=.new-list .hide-other-tabs-li > .new-text | |
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".new-list .hide-other-tabs-li > .new-text")).click();
        // 10 | click | css=.user-image > .place-holder-image | |
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".user-image > .place-holder-image")).click();
        // 11 | click | css=a > .new-item > .new-text | |
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a > .new-item > .new-text")).click();
        // 12 | close | | |
        // driver.close();
    }
    @AfterMethod (alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();

    }
}

public abstract class CapSc {
    public static WebDriver driver;


    public static void captureScreenShot (String screenshotName)  {

        File source = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File ("D:\\Maven\\eclipse-workspace\\mavenwebdriverjunit\\ScreenShots"+screenshotName+".png"));
            System.out.println("Screenshot Taken");
        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("Exception while Taking Screenshot " + e.getMessage());
        }


    }
}

public class CustomListener implements ITestListener{

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println("Failed Test");
        CapSc.captureScreenShot(result.getClass().getName()+"_"+result.getMethod().getMethodName());


    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: if there is any unhandled exception in java program it terminates program so it wont execute further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception `NullPointerException` under `@Test` method of Login class because `Setup.initialize();` initialize the driver in Setup class only You wont get the same reference under Login class and the driver instance under Login class remain null.

Either You need to return the driver instance from Setup class and use that in Login class or extend the Setup class in Login class

Comment: NarendraR I have it in a seperate package and importing the instance, The problem is it does not execute @ Test or @Aftermethod but runs @ BeforeMethod

Comment: Obviously. while it comes in Test method and execute  `driver.findElement(By.id("email")).click();` it through null pointer exception because driver is null as i mentioned in answer why and while it go to handle `onTestFailure` there is also driver is null in this line  `File source = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);`

Comment: Thanks for your help NarendraR It works now. I extended Setup class in Login class.